# find command output empty when redirected to a file

Tags: bash, find, io-redirection

I am trying to obtain a list of files using the `find` command as follows:

```
find . \( -iname @eaDir -o -iname .DS_Store -o -iname Thumbs.db \) -prune -o -mtime -25 -type f -printf "%P\n"
```

This is working fine.

However, if I try to redirect the output of the above command to a file, the latter remains empty:

```
FILES_TO_BACKUP=/tmp/__$$_myfiles.lst
find . \( -iname @eaDir -o -iname .DS_Store -o -iname Thumbs.db \) -prune -o -mtime -25 -type f -printf "%P\n" > $FILES_TO_BACKUP
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Which flavor of `find` is this? `find` on Mac OS X 10.11 lacks a `-printf` flag.

Comment: any chance you changed directories in-between?

Comment: Try adding the `-print` switch to `find` rather than `-printf`?

Comment: @thrig: I'm on CentOS 7.3 Core

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing user or similar between invoking from the script and running from command line? If so, perhaps the PATH has changed and a different find is being executed.

With peculiar problems like this I often run the command with 'strace' to see what it is doing differently.

From the two invocations that you gave I cannot eyeball any difference, there is perhaps a hint that you're running the second from a script, so perhaps that's where the difference is. Could you run 'pwd' before both, just to ensure that they are running from the same location and a 'which find' too may be helpful.

Comment: I'm not changing user, but yes, the 2nd one is being run from within a script. Am not familiar with `strace`. Tried displaying the output of `pwd` and I confirm that the path is correct. `which find`: `/usr/bin/find`

Comment: OK. After leaving the script run until the end, I did get the output in the file.